# Internet Explorer specific Error protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

Could someone help me in identifying what error is this.All my test cases pass in Chrome and in IE i am getting random errors like this on getText() and I do not understand what it is.

should compare  check total responses 
  Message:
    WebDriverError: Unable to determine type from: E. Last 1 characters read: E
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.1'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: Unable to determine type from: E. Last 1 characters read: E
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
    System info:  os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.1'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown

```
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.findElements(By(xpath, //qms-percentage-widget//div[@id='F2']//div[@class='default-widget']))
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.findElements (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1048:19)
    at ptor.waitForAngular.then (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:159:44)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
    at asyncRun (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
    at C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (C:AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at _onSuccess .js:79:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this exception, Your test fails when is trying to find element by xpath:

```
WebDriver.findElements(By(xpath, //qms-percentage-widget//div[@id='F2']//div[@class='default-widget']))
```